# MUlti Language support in JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

How to provide multi language support through JSP/Servlet? How to include static data of different languages at run time on basis of language selected?

Answer (score 10):

In a "plain vanilla" JSP/Servlet application, the best solution is the [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [fmt taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html). (just drop [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) How to use it is covered in [Oracle Java EE 5 tutorial part II chapter 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html) and in this answer: [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application).

If you're using a MVC framework such as Oracle JSF or Apache Struts, then you need to consult its specific documentation using keywords "internationalization" (i18n) or "localization" (l10n). In most cases they also provides specific tags for that, such as `<f:loadBundle>` in case of JSF, which in turn is covered in [Oracle Java EE 5 tutorial part II chapter 15](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaxw.html).

Those i18n tags already checks the default language/locale by [`ServletRequest#getLocale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29) (you don't need to do it "low-level" by checking the header as one suggested before --which would involve more work parsing the header as per the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4)). You can let the user choose the language itself (dropdown?) and store it in the session scope and instruct those taglibs to use it. Here's an example with JSTL fmt taglib:

```html
<fmt:setLocale value="${someSessionBean.locale}" />
```

..where `${someSessionBean.locale}` can return `en`, `en_US`, `en_UK`, etc. Those are in turn used by the [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API to load the localized text (you don't need to create/load the `ResourceBundle` itself, the taglibs already do that, just read the linked javadoc to learn a bit more about how it works).

If you want the language available as first pathinfo part of URL (such as `http://example.com/en/`, which is best for SEO), then you can best use a `Filter` for this which listens on `/*`, checks the pathinfo, splits the language part from it, stores/compares it as/with session value and forwards the request without language part in pathinfo further to the desired front controller.

Answer (score -1):

There are several important aspects to this issue. The first part is determining each request's locale. You can use something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest req ...;
String browserLocale = req.getHeader("Accept-Language"); // typically something like 'en'
```

Next, you need to decide how to manage the site's localized content. The most Java-like (not necessarily the best) approach is to externalize all messages using a ResourceBundle. You can learn about the core Java facilities for I18N, G13N in their [Isolating Locale Specific Data tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html).

Using only this approach is quite poor in my opinion. Different languages' content size differently, match better with different layouts, etc. So you can completely eliminate resource bundles (if you don't have a lot of multi-locale data) or augment the approach by using XSLT or other templating that is locale specific.

One very performant but high-development overhead approach is to use a servlet filter to redirect traffic to language- (or locale-) specific subsites. In this case, anyone hitting `http://my.domain.fake/xyz` would get redirected to `http://my.domain.fake/en/xyz`

Finally, it is worth noting that most of the serious web frameworks have their own I18N support. Their approaches differ based on the framework philosophy.

Comment: `ServletRequest.getLocale()` exists for a reason!

Answer (score -1):

We can to create messages.properties, messages_??*??.properties and to place this files into /scr/java directory. (where ??*?? - en_US, ru_RU and other)

Example lines into messages.properties:

```
About = About
Buy = Buy
Company = Company
ContactUs = Contact Us
```

Then to paste into jsp file for example lines:

```
   Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); 
   String lng = locale.getCountry(); 

   session.setAttribute( "language", lng);

   if (lng.equals( "UA"))
       locale = new Locale( "uk", "UA");
   else if (lng.equals( "RU"))
       locale = new Locale( "ru", "RU");
   else
       locale = Locale.US;

   ResourceBundle boundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "messages", locale);

   for (Enumeration e = boundle.getKeys(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
       String key = (String) e.nextElement();
       String s = boundle.getString(key);
       session.setAttribute( key, s);
   }
```

Now you can paste ${name} into next jsp code (${About}, ${Buy}, ...).

Comment: this is **not** the way you use the `ResourceBundle` and `Locale` classes! It shows a fundamental lack of comprehension of the subject.