# How to detect user locale and switch to it automatically?

Tags: javascript, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to internationalize a java web application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

greetings all
i want that when the client request a page
that page is automatically displayed in his locale
meaning (locale is detected then switch to it)
how to do so ?

Comment: misunderstood me, my question is very simple and clear i want on page load to detect the user locale and switch to it, Javascript function i guess ?

Comment: So you aren't doing localization at server side? Did you check the example in the duplicate question? `${pageContext.request.locale}` and so on? Why would you ever use JS for this?

Comment: i make the localization with spring framework.what do you mean by server side then? .and yes i checked the example but didn't find what i was looking for. i guess i will need js to detect the locale on page load and start applying localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html) on doing this in spring. And here is the [spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver).

However, do not depend on the browser's locale as this has some issues like inconsistent way in locale handling by browsers, forces user's to switch the browser locale when you have to support multiple languages within the same country. Provide an ability for the user to switch language on the home page itself.

Comment: i already know this, i guess i wasn't clear enough, i want on page load to detect the user locale and switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another](http://www.devsphere.com/mapping/docs/guide/internat.html) example you can try.