# JSF2 Internationalization property-file

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, jsf-2

I am trying to implement following example into my jsf2 app:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

But I don't understand how the app knows what property-file belongs to what language.

May you pls explain :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2 Interantionalization example question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667537/jsf2-interantionalization-example-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's done by [`ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API, not by JSF. The resource bundle filename should adhere the following pattern `name_ll_CC.properties`. The `_ll` part should be the lowercase [ISO 693-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code. It is optional and only required whenever the `_CC` part is present. The `_CC` part should be the uppercase [ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code. It is optional and often only used to distinguish between country-specific language dialects, like American English (`_en_US`) and British English (`_en_UK`).

The right file is determined based on the [`Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) of the current request. JSF will pass the one of [`UIViewRoot#getLocale()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getLocale%28%29) to `ResourceBundle`. If the `name_ll_CC.properties` file is absent, then the `ResourceBundle` will scan for `name_ll.properties` file. If it is absent as well, then the `ResourceBundle` will fallback to the default properties file whose locale you can specify as `<default-locale>` entry in `faces-config.xml`. If an entry is absent as well, then it will finally scan for `name.properties` instead.

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - ResourceBundle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html)
- [How to internationalize a JSP/JSTL web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application/4278571#4278571)
- [How to internationalize a JSF 2.0 web application using UTF-8 properties files without native2ascii?](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/)