# Adding i18n support after the fact

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization

I apologise in advance if this is a bit of a subjective/discussion type question. What I would like to have are good ways to retrofit locale information to a web application that is primarily JSP. The framework is... well non existent, just lots of **.jsp** pages with tons of scripting and **JavaScript** twiddling. I just started, so I'm not yet in any position to suggest an overhaul, although I think i'll get around to that at some point.

Now, someone on the team has suggested some *"easy"* javascript based content localization using browser locale or somesuch. This is setting off all kinds of alarms in my head.

But what would be a good way to use Java Locale support via JSP pages, that would then be easy to extend to a nice framework like JSF 2?

This is what I was thinking:

- Move all possible display strings to ***_locale.properties** files
- Build a utility class that reads from proper file based on locale info in request/session
- Embed said utility class in all jsp files
- Replace all **<title>Page 1</title>** into **<title>localeUtils.getString("page1.title)</title>**

Suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to internationalize a java web application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application) Just use standard JSTL `fmt` taglib.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to move to a framework right away that supports localization out of the box ([Spring](http://www.springsource.org) comes to mind here), then you'll have to come up with your own solution and the one you have provided seems like a good start. Definitely use property files to store your locale-specific strings and use the [supported Java locale IDs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html) in the name of each locale-specific property file.