# How to set JSTL locale from Java code?

Tags: java, jstl, locale, setlocale

I want to set the JSTL locale which is used by `<fmt:formatNumber>` and friends. I know this is possible with `<fmt:setLocale>`, but I need to do it dynamically (depending on user data retrieved from my DB) and would prefer Java code - a filter class, to be precise.

I thought setting the session attribute `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale` to my desired `Locale` instance would do the trick, but it is ignored: The JSTL tags keep using the browser locale.

I verified there are no page context or request attributes of the same name.

So what am I doing wrong? Or do I really need to do it from a JSP?

Reading the JSTL code, I found references to a `LocalizationContext` and think I need to set one. I couldn't quite figure out exactly how it fits into the picture or how to set one, though.

Comment: Have you tried to set the java value into request, via request.setAttribute()? JSTL (can also) read(s) the request scope.

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you need the 2nd:

**3 ways to set JSTL locale:** 
/as well as default application resource bundle, time zone, and data source/

1. Set by a JSTL action – this allows specification of scope by the scope attribute.

   ```
   <fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
   ```
2. Set Programmatically – allows specification of scope via the Config API.

   ```
   import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config;
   (...)
   Config.set( session, Config.FMT_LOCALE, new java.util.Locale("en", "US") )
   // or Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US") (java 1.7 and later)
   ```
3. Set by *Context* Initialization Parameters – specifies value used if setting not found in any of the standard scopes.

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale</param-name>
       <param-value>en_US</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

[jstl-quick-reference (PDF)](http://bellsouthpwp.net/b/i/billsigg/jstl-quick-reference.pdf)

Answer (score 12):

You can just use EL in `<fmt:setLocale>`. It doesn't need to be a hardcoded value or something.

Here's an example:

```
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
```

If the language was supplied as request parameter with name `language`, then it will be set. Else if the language was already previously set in the session by attribute name `language`, then stick to it instead. Else use the user supplied locale in the request header.

If you do a `session.setAttribute("language", language)` in your filter code, then it will be used -if no request parameter is been set.

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: I know I don't need hardcoded values for setLocale. I would still prefer a "clean" solution in a Java class, though.

Comment: I honestly don't see how fiddling with view taglib specific classes from inside the controller is more "clean".

Comment: This is a matter of taste, obviously. I myself would prefer to not rely on a JSP (include) to do the right thing. Java code, on the other hand, is covered by unit tests, can be refactored with tool support and so on...

Comment: BalusC, probably what OP wants is to avoid the need for calling `<fmt:setLocale>` in each jsp in the DRY tradition.

Comment: @Jens: Just set the necessary attribute in the filter and reference it in `<fmt:setLocale>`? I don't see how that would break unit tests or refactoring. @Tahir: Use templates/`<jsp:include>` wisely.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale' is overridden by the browser's locale. JSTL uses the browser's locale and if that's not found, it uses a fallback locale. So you can set a request attribute to specify that locale. Add this line to your controller

```
request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale.request", "en-us");
```

Using this will set the locale which JSTL will use. Note the *.request* in the attribute name, if you set this attribute to some other scope, you'll have to use different suffix. For HttpSession the suffix is *.session*, for ServletContext the suffix is *.application*

Answer (score 0):

If you are dependent on data from DB, may be there is better way to insert this logic into your `'router'` or `'controller'` (depends on which framework are you using). Just extend url with parameter `?lang='en'`

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't understand how this helps JSTL. I would still have to add the <fmt:setLocale> tag to the JSP, right? This is exactly the thing I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. In the servlet, you can set the locale by creating a session attribute, like so:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale.session", "ko-KR");
```