# The <fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale }" scope="session" />tag is not used

Tags: java, jsp, localization

I use MyEclipse to compile my program,and I want to achieve *internationalization*, so I choose use the `fmt` tag.

The follow is the code:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale }" scope="session" />
```

Book says that `${param.locale }` can get the browser's `default-language`. In order to change the language, I use two languages, English and Chinese. Though I set the browser's `default-language` to English, when I reload the jsp page, the language is always Chinese. Could you tell me what's the matter?

full codes:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"; %> 
<fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale }" scope="session" /> <fmt:setBundlebasename="loginpage"/> <input type="text" id="text1" /> <br/> <input type="password" id="text2" /> <br /> <input type="submit" id="smb" value="<fmt:message key="login_sub" />" />
```

Comment: would you show your code,please?

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale }" scope="session" />
<fmt:setBundlebasename="loginpage"/>                                <input type="text" id="text1" />
<br/>                                                               <input type="password" id="text2" />  <br />            
<input type="submit" id="smb" value="<fmt:message key="login_sub" />" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not true. The EL `param` object maps a request parameter name to a single value. If `param.locale` exists then you can set `locale` through `fmt:setLocale/>` tag.

Text from this article - [Formatting and internationalization through custom tags](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0415/)

> The locale used by the JSTL tags when formatting data is normally
>   determined by examining the Accept-Language header sent by a user's
>   browser as part of each HTTP request. If no such header is present,
>   then JSTL provides a set of JSP configuration variables you can set to
>   specify a default locale. If these configuration variables have not
>   been set, then the JVM's default locale is used, which is obtained
>   from the operating system the JSP container is running on.

and take a look at SO thread - [How to set JSTL locale from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126542/how-to-set-jstl-locale-from-java-code)

Comment: Though I'm not completed understand,I think what you said is reasonable.I will study it carefully later.Thank you.