# The JSTL formatting library: `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt` doesn't work at all if there is no `Accept-Language` header

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

The JSTL formatting library: `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt` doesn't work at all if there is no `Accept-Language` header. can anyone explain why this is and how to get around it (Except for providing the header)

For instance:  will format the date through a normal web browser, but using telnet or curl to request the page it doesn't format it correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set JSTL locale from Java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126542/how-to-set-jstl-locale-from-java-code)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate for the second half of my question, the first part still remains unanswered.  Why, if I don't have that header in the request, do I not get any formatting, what-so-ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why this is happening, this seems to be expected behaviour.

As per the JSTL spec [on the Oracle site](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr052/):

> ### 9.9 `<fmt:formatDate>`
>
> **Null & Error Handling**
>
> - If `value` is null, remove the scoped variable if it is specified (see attributes `var` and `scope`).
> - If `timeZone` is null or empty, it is handled as if it was missing.
> - If this action fails to determine a formatting locale, it uses `java.util.Date.toString()` as the output format.

So as per your error, if no locale is set on the server-side & the request also doesn't pass one either, JSTL is falling back to a `toString()` call on the date, rather than e.g. the locale of the JVM settings.

Comment: At the risk of shooting the messenger: Why, if I specify a pattern, does it give a fish about locale. (Thanks for digging this out of the spec for me)

Comment: I know what you mean, especially if you've specified, e.g. "dd-mm-yy", it should be valid fairly universally. Maybe the thinking is for day/month names used in patterns, though still not a reason not to fall back to the JVM values