# JSTL - how to get a value of value?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have this in my jsp page :    `${category.name_ENG}`  which has "Car" as value

but i have the local language in an another varialbes : `${locale}`. So in my jsp i want to display the car value depending on the locale variable.

I tried those :

```
${category.name_${locale}}
${category['name_${locale}']}
${category['name_{locale}']}
```

but none of them worked?
any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use JSTL `<c:set>` to concatenate a string in EL and then use brace notation `[]` to access properties with a dynamic key.

```xml
<c:set var="name" value="name_${locale}" />
${category[name]}
```

By the way, if the sole functional requirement is internationalization/localization, then there are way much better ways than fiddling like this: [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)