# Expression lang with JSP/JSTL nesting values

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have the following data:

> records{doc_Title="title",doc_Title_en="en",doc_Title_es="es",doc_Title_fr="fr"...}

Also, in my jsp, I have the language value in my `lang` variable which varies from page to page. Depending on the `lang` value, the corresponding `doc_Title` has to be displayed. Is this achievable using EL?

`${record.docTitle}` can be directly accessed which would display the value. but I want the `lang` value to be dynamically changed while accessing the value from the records.

For example: lang="en";

```
<c:set var="docName" value="record.docTitle_${lang}" />
```

But, `${docName}` displays "record_docTitle_en" and not "en" (the value). How is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtained the answer for this from [JSTL - how to get a value of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162264/jstl-how-to-get-a-value-of-value) and thus the code went like this:

```
    <c:set var="docname" value="docName_${lang}" />
    ${record[docname]}
```