# Load files based on Language in Stripes Framework

Tags: java, jsp, localization, stripes

Morning, 
I'm looking for a way to load different files based on the language of the browser using the stripes framework.
e.g.

`if (getLocal() == Local.US) load(testsheet_us);`

same question for the jsp files:

```
<c:if test="${local == Local.US")> include('about_us')</c:if>
```

or something similar.

Erin

Comment: I know absolutely nothign about Stripes, but in plain JSP you'd use JSTL `fmt` for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local of the request is on the actionBean [context](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/ActionBeanContext.html). In an actionBean you could code like this:

```
if (getContext().getLocale() == Local.US) load(testsheet_us) {
    // do something
}
```

In JSP it could be done like this:

```
<%-- this will go into a general include file: --%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="context" value="${actionBean.context}"/>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("US", java.util.Locale.US); %>

<c:if test="${context.locale.country == US}">
  <jsp:include page="about_us.jsp"/>
</c:if>
```

But unless each locale has a different layout, you normally would use [ResouceBundles](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/) to localize your application. Localized fields would look like this:

```
<fmt:message key="aboutus.name"/><br>
<fmt:message key="aboutus.companyVision"/><br>
```

Stripes also localizes Stripes tags with resourcebundles, see: [Stripes Localization](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Localization), [Stripes Multiple Resource Bundles](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Multiple+Resource+Bundles)

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for the first Option.