# How to get some properties by key from JSP

Tags: jsp, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to internationalize a java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

I'm new in JSP technology and now I'm thinking about some internationalization of my page.
I'd like you to tell me how to get some properties from my .properties file(specified by locale) and where to put it in?
Will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the fmt:message tag in the JSTL tag libraries. And you can readily stick the properties files in the WEB-INF/classes directory of your WAR.