# Default locale is not getting set to UK using <fmt:setLocale value="en_GB" />

Tags: java, jsp

I am setting the default locale to UK using  in jsp but its not reflecting. Why is this so? Is there any other way to do this or can I do this from Java end?

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `<fmt:setLocale>` **before** `<fmt:setBundle>`.

```html
<fmt:setLocale value="en_GB" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
```

If you call it afterwards, it would have no effect because the bundle is already loaded at that point.

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with `fmt:formatDate` you should specify the timezone, e.g.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${myDate}" pattern="dd MMM HH:mm" timeZone="BST"/>
```

Values for timeZone you can get from `java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`

**Edit**

Try using the `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` class:

```
Config.set(getServletContext(), Config.FMT_LOCALE, "en_GB");
```

Comment: Thank you Andre but I am not having problem with fmt:formatDate I am unable to set my locale to UK which is showing some problem in fmt:formatNumber when the browser locale is changed to Polish. SO I want to make the locale default to UK

Comment: What happens when you try to set the Locale programmatically via `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.set(getServletContext(), Config.FMT_LOCALE, "en_GB");`

Answer (score 0):

If by "default locale" you mean actually calling `java.util.Locale.setDefault()` then this is not possible in jstl since it would affect the whole application and not just the user acessing the current page. The `fmt:setLocale` tag sets the locale for the pages [LocalizationContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/fmt/LocalizationContext.html) which is then used by `fmt:message`, `fmt:formatNumber`, `fmt:parseNumber`, `fmt:formatDate`, and `fmt:parseDate`.