# Accessing i18n properties file from "webcontent" or "WEB-INF\local" folder

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am developing a JSP / Servlet pages which needs to be i18n. The example codes which I have seen on the internet are using JSTL's setlocal and setbundle tags. And they are adding the `.properties` file in the java source folder or `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 and JSTL1.2 jar files for the project.

I wanted to know can we added the `.properties` file in say `webcontent\i18n` or `WEB-INF\local` folder. And access it using JSTL tags?

Answer (score 3):

It has to go in the classpath. They're under the covers loaded by [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) which loads them by default form the classpath. So, putting it outside the classpath won't work. You can always put them in a (sub)package like so `/WEB-INF/classes/local/filename.properties`. You should then only access it with basename `local.filename` instead of `filename`.

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)