# how to internationalize <form:option /> values for a <form:select /> in jsp?

Tags: forms, jsp, bundle, html-select

Please, mind the code snippet bellow:

```
        <form:select path="type">
            <form:option value="national"><s:message code="holiday-list-type1" /></form:option>
            <form:option value="state"><s:message code="holiday-list-type2" /></form:option>
            <form:option value="city"><s:message code="holiday-list-type3" /></form:option>
            <form:option value="other"><s:message code="holiday-list-type4" /></form:option>
        </form:select>
```

I'd like the value for each `<form:option ... />`  to have a value defined in the bundle, instead of being hard-coded on the JSP.

How can I do so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing the following:

```
<form:select path="type">
    <form:option value="holiday-list-type1"><s:message code="holiday-list-type1" /></form:option>
    <form:option value="holiday-list-type2"><s:message code="holiday-list-type2" /></form:option>
    <form:option value="holiday-list-type3"><s:message code="holiday-list-type3" /></form:option>
    <form:option value="holiday-list-type4"><s:message code="holiday-list-type4" /></form:option>
</form:select>
```

This way I persist the value holiday-list-type{1-4} (which is the key to my messages bundle) to the database and the JSP returns the internationalized value.

Hope this helps someone too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the LINK to externalize all the Strings based upon the language.

@BalusC Sir  given an Answer which is almost like an tutorial :)

[How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: thanks for your input, but my case is a litte more specific from that. :)