# Web application in jsp/servlets - localization using fmt:message

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, bundle

I'm writing simple www application using jsp and servlets on Tomcat 7.0. It's multilingual and i want to externalize all messages for easy translation. I am trying to achieve this using fmt:message tag. This is my test page:

SimplePage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="application" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="localization.message" var="b" />
<html>
<body>
    <fmt:message key="key1" bundle="${b}" />
</body>
```

message_en_US.properties

```
key1=test
```

Output of page is:

```
???key1???
```

I've put message_en_US.properties into source folder named "localization". I've tried also putting it into WEB-INF, WebContent and src (with changing basename of bundle) - result is the same. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application/4278571#4278571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it in a source folder named `localization` you don't need to prefix it with localization.

```html
<fmt:setBundle basename="message" var="b" />
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer the concrete problem? OP doesn't seem to have done anything wrong with regard to this.

Comment: Well... but it is working now, i mean since i deleted localization prefix. But i wonder is this right place to keep my localization files?

Comment: @BalusC It works for me too. I'm doubting myself now, but the `fmt` library and its `bundle` tag uses classpath resources to evaluate your bundles. So putting them in source folder is one way to do it.

Comment: OP mentioned that it's placed in a source folder named `localization`, which I interpreted as package `localization`, then the basename of `localization.message` should be right. But apparently that fixed it. Look like there's some confusion/misgrasping of terms used.

Comment: No, he said `into source folder named "localization". `