# How to set the locale using the java variable in <fmt:setLocale>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the language code in java variable. I want to set that code into setLocale value like

```
<%

String lang="en";

%>
<fmt:setLocale value="${lang}" scope="session"/>
```

But this was not working correctly. But when i set like

`<fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="session"/>` ,it was working perfectly. The language may be es,de... So i want to set the value like  `<fmt:setLocale value="${lang}" scope="session"/>`.

Is any solutions? Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using the JSTL tag for `<c:set>` to set the `lang` variable instead?

Comment: @tieTYT yes set tag will do the task.

Answer (score 0):

As  mentioned in comment use `set` tag

```
 <c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ?
          param.language : not empty language  ? language :
                        pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
                                           <fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
```

See here for full description [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: This was not change the language for the entire session. Some pages only get change.

Comment: I have 18 jsp pages.I have included the setLocale code in all tha pages. When i use like value="en" , it works fine. But i cant set the value dynamically.

Comment: Are you setting the value value="${not empty param.language ?
          param.language : not empty language  ? language :
                        pageContext.request.locale}.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="<%=lang%>" scope="session"/>
```