# get text from properties file for a href title

Tags: jsp

I want to make a tooltip using an anchor tag with the text coming from a properties file.

How do I get this text from application.properties to the anchor's title attribute?

```
msg.delete=click to delete this item.
```

JSP

```
<a title="{tooltips.delete}" href="do something">
  <img src="../images/delete_icon.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, able to solve it using s text like `title="<s:text name="tooltips.delete"/>"`.

Answer (score 0):

use ResourceBundle inside jsp to get value from properties file. use `$` operator to fetch corresponding value for your key.

i.e  tooltips.delete = User will be deteled (entry in application.properites)

```
<a title="${tooltips.delete}" href="do something">
```

use [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application) question to resolve your issue. Even though question is about Internationalization you can learn from it to read properties file and place value inside href.

Comment: have you loaded application.properties using ResourceBundle class ?