# Internationalization jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, internationalization

I have below jsp code.

```
<section class="loginform cf">  
    <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">  
        <ul>  
            <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>  
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required></li>  
            <li><label for="password">Password</label>  
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>  
            <li>  
            <input type="submit" value="Login"></li>  
        </ul>  
    </form>  
</section>
```

Here i want to externalize all label names and label names will be shown based on the locale.
Basically i need i18n for jsp labels. How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This should cover your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application

Comment: @Sotirios, Thanks for providing the useful link..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is by creating property files for each country_locale you want your labels in and pulling values from the right file (e.g. use label_properties_ *format) depending on the user's locale. The property names can stay the same in each file, but the values should be right for that file* .