# No MessageBundle after tomcat deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, internationalization, jstl

I'm trying to internationalize my `servlet` project, so I placed all the `MessageBundle` files to `com.project.i18n` package:

```
$ ls src/main/java/com/project/i18n/
Internationalization.java     MessagesBundle_fr.properties  MessagesBundle.properties     MessagesBundle_us.properties
```

When I run tomcat via `mvn tomcat:run` everything works fine and I get the right language; but if deploy the `project.war` file to `tomcat/webapps` derectory then the localized messages are not working anymore, when I check the package path in `tomcat/webapps` there is not `MessageBundle` files:

```
 $ ls webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/project/i18n/
   Internationalization.class
```

This is the `index.jsp`:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="fr" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.project.i18n.MessagesBundle" />
...
<fmt:message key="home.welcome" />
..
```

anyhelp how to resolve this issue? tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Don't MessageBundle files must go to src/main/resources instead of src/main/java?

Have you got any filter on your sourceDirectory configuration?

Comment: its a sevlet project not jsf

Answer (score 0):

Internationalization files should be in `/src/main/resources` folder. Refer the following.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxw.html

[How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: The link you have pasted also placed bundle files to `package` not to `main/resoruces`

Comment: Yes, it should be in the package but within `resources`, not in `java`. i.e.: `src/main/resources/com/project/messages/`

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `MessageBundle` files to `src/main/resources` and modified the `setBundle` on index page as below:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="MessagesBundle" />
```

Now it works.