# How do I support multiple locales for the same language in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to make my jsf application support resources from multiple locales.

I've already created the contents on the resources folder and that works fine when I have the following on my faces.config:

```
<supported-locale>en</supported-locale>

<supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
```

However, I'd like to support US English, Canadian English and UK English, for instance.

How do I go about doing that?

```
<supported-locale>en_CA</supported-locale>
<supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
```

The above doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to internationalize a java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: @PaulVargas This question is about JSF, so no duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The supported locales actually work as described above:

```
<supported-locale>en_CA</supported-locale>
<supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
```

My problem was that en_CA and en_US should not be inside the "en" folder in the resources folder. They should be subfolders of resources.

```
.resources
..en
..en_CA
..en_US
```

Rather ugly but I guess that's how JSF wants it. Nested folders would be more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

have you read the oracle documentation? It's Chapter 17 about Internationalization and Localizing Web Applications from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxu.html). just read and follow the documentation and I'm sure it will work.

Comment: What a great constructive answer! In fact, that might just be the answer to almost every question here on SO.

Comment: Upvote or accept the answer if it helps u solve with your problem.