# How to include HTML code within prime ui or jquery datatable "columns" option's headerText?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internationalization

I am trying to apply internationalization to my web app that uses JSP pages.I found this link [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application) and it really helped me.

However I am now trying to use the given tag **fmt:message** tag within my primeui datatable's headerText so that I can see column name of my datatable in spanish language.But it's being displayed as text on the screen.Whereas I want it to function as it does on my JSP page i.e to pick user.data.userName="spanish translation for username" from my properties file text_es.properties.

Below is the code for my datatable which is included in script tag on my JSP:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tbllocal').puidatatable({
        caption : 'Inbox Tasks',
        paginator : {
            rows : 5
        },
        columns : [
        {
            field : 'userName',
            **headerText : '<fmt:message key='user.data.userName'/>',**
            sortable : true
        },{
            field : 'userEmailId',
            headerText : 'userEmailId',
            sortable : true
        } ],
        datasource : function(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : 'crud',
                dataType : "json",
                context : this,
                success : function(response) {
                    callback.call(this, response);
                }
            });
        },

        selectionMode : 'single',
        rowSelect : function(event, data) {
            $('#messages').puigrowl('show', [ {
                severity : 'info',
                summary : 'Row Selected',
                detail : (data.firstName + ': ' + data.lastName)
            } ]);
        },
        rowUnselect : function(event, data) {
            $('#messages').puigrowl('show', [ {
                severity : 'info',
                summary : 'Row Unselected',
                detail : (data.firstName + ': ' + data.lastName)
            } ]);
        },
        jsonReader : {
            response : "response"

        }
    });
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no support for including html in datatable header till primeui 2.0 i have also posted this question on frimeui forum please refer following link for further details 
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=42417