# JSON, Servlet and i18n

Tags: java, json, servlets, internationalization

I am working on a back-end project where request is coming as JSON object to my servlet and response is sent as an JSON object as well. I found this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951891/jsp-i18n-works-on-each-page-separately-after-setting-default-language-in-filter) useful but need help to understand how filter can be used in my aforementioned back-end scenario to globalized my all classes/APIs through filter

I am new to Java and looking for advice that is it possible? OR I have to manually call ResourceBundle for each class

Comment: what do you mean by "globalize my all classes/API  through filter". What are you really trying to accomplish? Please elaborate it.

Comment: in MVC model we can write a servlet filter (link is provided in my question) that sets country and language globally for all requests/responses for wohle jsp files but here I am getting country & language as JSON parameter and there is no view in my hand that is controlled my front-end designer

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving your i18n in json payload, you may try doing something as following

```
 // this parses the json
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("yourPramName")); 
    Iterator it = jObj.keys(); 
    
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String key = it.next(); // get key
        Object o = jObj.get(key); // get value
     req.getSession().setAttribute(key, o);
    }
```

Comment: This code has to be written in each class whereas I am looking for a code example that should be written once in whole project and use it in all classes rather than code it in every class. I have given example in my question that in MVC model we can use servlet filter that do this but right now I don't have control over "VIEW" as this is controlled by front-end designer and I am working on back-end

Comment: You don't have to write it in each class. You can write this once in your filter. What you really need is a request object, The doFilter method of a servlet filter has both request and response objects as parameter. Once you have access to the request object , you can get the value and persist the data in a session.