# How to send Japanese text to backend Java code via http get?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I want send **を伴う出力となって** to backend java code via http get request.
My get call url is http://localhost:8080/test/getID?id=%E3%82%92%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%86%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6

Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCaseId")
    public ModelAndView showCaseId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String msg = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println("URL:"+msg);
        return new ModelAndView("showID", "idList", null);
    }
```

Above piece of code prints **URL:ãä¼´ãåºåã¨ãªã£ã¦**.
So what's change i need to do get the exact Japanese text what i have passed from front end.

Comment: What happens when you just write `System.out.println("を伴う出力となって ");` ? Maybe it's your terminal's problem. Check there first. Then look at the webserver....

Comment: Btw, that's not Chinese text, those are Japanese characters.

Comment: Have a look at posts by BalusC e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application

Comment: @RayToal :Yes,It prints **を伴う出力となって**

Comment: @Aify : May be its Japanese text. But how can i send those text?

Comment: What application server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `msg` line to:

```
String msg = new String(
    request.getParameter("id").getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
```

If that will work it means that your application server (Tomcat? jetty?) is not configured correctly to handle UTF-8 in URLs.

Comment: Then this is a workaround, and the solution would be to configure Tomcat or jetty correctly. What would this solution do if it was deployed to a Tomcat or jetty that was already configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse IDE, you need to check Text File encoding. Please check with the following figure.[image]

Comment: UTF-8 is selected.But not helping

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the submitted query string is getting mutilated on the way into your server-side script, because getParameter() uses ISO-8559-1 instead of UTF-8.

So i modified my code as below and now its working

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCaseId")
    public ModelAndView showCaseId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String msg = new String(request.getParameter("id").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8")
        System.out.println("URL:"+msg);
        return new ModelAndView("showID", "idList", null);
    }
```

I found this solution in http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__lxgr-hi_i_am_havi.html.