# How to create mult language web application in jsp servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization

I have created web application but not sure,How to implement multiple language support like hindi etc.Does I18N can solve this or just google translator can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out BalusC's answer here: [How to internationalize/localize a JSP/Servlet web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

BalusC:

> In case of a basic JSP/Servlet webapplication, the basic approach
> would be using [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fmt` taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) in combination with
> [resource bundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html). Resource bundles contain key-value pairs where
> the key is a constant which is the same for all languages and the
> value differs per language. Resource bundles are usually [properties
> files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) which are loaded by [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API. This can
> however be customized so that you can load the key-value pairs from
> for example a database.
>
> Here's an example how to internationalize the login form of your
> webapplication with properties file based resource bundles.
>
> ---
>
> 1. Create the following files and put them in some package, e.g. `com.example.i18n` (in case of Maven, put them in the package
>    structure inside `src/main/resources`).
>
>    `text.properties` (contains key-value pairs in the default language, usually English)
>
>    ```
>     login.label.username = Username
>     login.label.password = Password
>     login.button.submit = Sign in
>    ```
>
>    ---
>
>    `text_nl.properties` (contains Dutch (`nl`) key-value pairs)
>
>    ```
>     login.label.username = Gebruikersnaam
>     login.label.password = Wachtwoord
>     login.button.submit = Inloggen
>    ```
>
>    ---
>
>    `text_es.properties` (contains Spanish (`es`) key-value pairs)
>
>    ```
>     login.label.username = Nombre de usuario
>     login.label.password = Contraseña
>     login.button.submit = Acceder
>    ```
>
>    The resource bundle filename should adhere the following pattern `name_ll_CC.properties`. The `_ll` part should be the lowercase [ISO
>    693-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code. It is optional and only required whenever the
>    `_CC` part is present. The `_CC` part should be the uppercase [ISO
>    3166-1 Alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code. It is optional and often only used to
>    distinguish between country-specific language dialects, like [American
>    English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English) (`_en_US`) and [British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) (`_en_GB`).
>
>    ---
> 2. If not done yet, install JSTL. If you're running on a Servlet 2.5 container or newer (Tomcat 6.0 and so on) and your `web.xml` is
>    declared conform the Servlet 2.5 specification, then just put
>    [jstl-1.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.
>
>    ---
> 3. Create the following example JSP file and put it in web content folder.
>
>    `login.jsp`
>
> ```html
> <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
> <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
> <c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? 
>   param.language : not empty language ? language :
>   pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
> <fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
> <fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="${language}">
>     <head>
>         <title>JSP/JSTL i18n demo</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <form>
>             <select id="language" name="language" onchange="submit()">
>                 <option value="en" ${language == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''}>English</option>
>                 <option value="nl" ${language == 'nl' ? 'selected' : ''}>Nederlands</option>
>                 <option value="es" ${language == 'es' ? 'selected' : ''}>Español</option>
>             </select>
>         </form>
>         <form method="post">
>             <label for="username"><fmt:message key="login.label.username" />:</label>
>             <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
>             <br>
>             <label for="password"><fmt:message key="login.label.password" />:</label>
>             <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
>             <br>
>             <fmt:message key="login.button.submit" var="buttonValue" />
>             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="${buttonValue}">
>         </form>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> The `<c:set var="language">` manages the current language. If the language was supplied as request parameter (by language dropdown),
> then it will be set. Else if the language was already previously set
> in the session, then stick to it instead. Else use the user supplied
> locale in the request header.
>
> The `<fmt:setLocale>` sets the locale for resource bundle. It's important that this line is *before* the `<fmt:setBundle>`.
>
> The `<fmt:setBundle>` initializes the resource bundle by its base name (that is, the full qualified package name until with the sole
> name without the `_ll_CC` specifier).
>
> The `<fmt:message>` retrieves the message value by the specified bundle key.
>
> The `<html lang="${language}">` informs the searchbots what language the page is in so that it won't be marked as duplicate
> content (thus, good for SEO).
>
> The language dropdown will immediately submit by JavaScript when another language is chosen and the page will be refreshed with the newly chosen language.
>
> ---
>
> You however need to keep in mind that properties files are by default
> read using ISO-8859-1 character encoding. You would need to escape
> them by unicode escapes. This can be done using the JDK-supplied
> `native2ascii.exe` tool. See also [this article section](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JavaPropertiesFiles) for more
> detail.
>
> A theoretical alternative would be to supply a bundle with a custom
> [`Control`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) to load those files as UTF-8, but that's unfortunately
> not supported by the basic JSTL `fmt` taglib. You would need to manage
> it all yourself with help of a `Filter`. There are (MVC) frameworks
> which can handle this in a more transparent manner, like JSF, see also
> [this article](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/).

Comment: Thank you it works fine but how to post current language details to servlet.Is it possilbe by using session setAttribute?

Comment: yes, i think sessions is supposed to be how you do it. (unless you want to keep checking with each request what the user's language preference is)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general idea:

make for every language 1 separate key-value-pair file

- every word or sentence has a unique key (hi=Hello, hi=Hola ect ect)
- dont put hardcoded text in the jsp
- create a singleton that will load all the languages into a hashmap at startup
- create 1 tag that will get the text from the hashmap based on the given locale 
  and unique key
- use the tag in the jsp `<sp:message code="hi" />`
- get the locale from the browsers request (or the user's preference)

..Or just use Spring which does all these things for you.