# Redirect with the previous url

Tags: java

Problem in the next - I want to make a multi language Java web application. The task is to enable all the pages of the application to switch between languages ​​(made `header.jsp` with a change of language and connect it through include in other JSP pages), as after changing the language I return to the page from where the user called the language change.

For example, the user logged in, passed parameters through POST, and then immediately clicked the language change. 
`request.getHeader ("Referer")` - works, but only with GET, and I need it to do with POST (when parameters in the request body).

Help please, push the thought.

Comment: If you are using JSP, you should use standard internationalization features in Java to make multilanguage web applications.

Comment: How should I do this? Tell me please.

Comment: Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application

Comment: This may help as well: http://www.wideskills.com/jsp/jsp-internationalization